# Excel VBA date format display different result in different pc?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm facing a problem here in Excel VBA.
I set `Today()` as values in the column and the result display is **2015/1/6 0:00** but in other computer, the result is **42010**.

Guys, do you have any solution to avoid this problem to occur in a different pc?
 This problem occur when I trying to copy and paste from one sheet to another sheet in other pc. I want the result **2015/1/6 0:00** to be display in all computers.

Comment: Why are you using `WorksheetFunction.Today()` in VBA rather than the simpler (and VBA native) `Date` ?

Comment: Because i want to display today's date in the records and this problem occur when i copy and paste the info from one sheet to other sheet

Comment: When viewed tomorrow, should the date show the 6th or the 7th? IOW, should it update on a daily basis on the remote worksheet or be remain as the day it was copied? Can you show a few lines of code that provide the copy/paste operation to the remote worksheet?

Comment: actually i just paste the values only, not the operation :)

Answer (score 1):

That does not appear to be a regular date format by any international regional standard so you will have to format the cell (Ctrl+1) on the worksheet using a custom number format or with a subsequent VBA line like,

```
Range("A2:A10").NumberFormat = "yyyy/m/d h:mm"
```

If you are already in VBA, the latter solution provides more versatility.